# Change password in Task Scheduler in script

Tags: scripting

I'm changing password every month for all scheduled tasks I created in Task Scheduler. This is because our security policy expires our password every month.

Due to increasing number of scheduled tasks I'm creating, it eats up a lot of time in just changing password within Task Scheduler.

My question is: Is there a way in script to change password in one run specifying the tasks,  DOMAIN\username, and password?

I know there's a security risk in putting the password in script. The password in script will be removed after the running it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your security policy won't allow you to set up an account with a non-expiring password. Can you create a batch file with at.exe commands to schedule and execute jobs? Here is an example in case you haven't used the command before:

[HOW TO: Use the At.exe Command to Schedule a Backup in Windows NT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313289)